# Rails - Devise, is it possible to use user_signed_in? without authenticate_user!?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm doing a sort of notepad in rails. the main page has this form for notes with the only field "content". Everyone can create a note but I'm trying to add authentication using devise so users can sign up and save their notes.

So I have my site controller with index as uniq method

### site controller

```
def index
  @note = Note.new
end
```

and then a notes controller with the create action

### notes controller

```
def create
  @note = if user_signed_in?
    current_user.notes.build(params[:note])
  else
    Note.new(params[:note])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @note.save
      format.js
    else
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I though that would work but devise helpers only seems to work when I add

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

on the controller I need.

is it possible to check if there's a user without the before_filter? or should I make 2 create methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can try to add this before filter:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => []
```

It might add the helpers (if it's really needed) but won't apply to any action.

Comment: I've been using your workaround, and it does the work but I'm not sure if its the best way. Anyway, thanks :)... if I don't find another answer with the devise team then I'll check your answer as correct